# How to use iFrame to access a published asp.net website

Tags: html, asp.net, iis, iframe

I have a website that I need to call using iFrame from another website. I have published and deployed this website on IIS on my local machine. I created a test page to test if it would work with iFrame. But the website doesn't show up. I get an error message stating *"Hmm, we can't reach this page."* I am able to access the website directly from web browser using the URL. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here, and how I should approach this problem? Thanks in advance!

Following is the html page from where I am calling the target website in an iFrame:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <iframe height = "1000px" width="1000px" src="http://localhost:xxxx/Default.asp">
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you please open your HTML page in Google Chrome and then press F12 and check Developer Tools console. Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: No. There are no errors but I am able to see the website in Chrome, Firefox and IE. For some reason, it wasn't working for Microsoft Edge. Probably shouldn't have tried on there either. But thanks! Really appreciate it!